# GET petition doesn't return anything and stays thinking

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, asp.net-core

I'm making an API with GET petition that sends all data of my DB.

It makes all the function and gets all data without problem but when arrives to the return line it stays there thinking and never return anything.

```
        [HttpGet("GetAll")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public ActionResult<List<Lead>> GetAll()
        {
            ActionResult<List<Lead>> list = BadRequest();

            string query = @$"SELECT LeadID, CompanyName, CompanyAddress1, CompanyAddress2, CompanyCity,
                CompanyState, PersonFirstName, PersonPhoneNumber, PersonEmail, Details, Distribuidor,
                Comercial, TipoEstablecimiento, NombreChef, MailChef, JefeCompras, EmailJefeCompras,
                EmailRestaurante, Latitud, Longitud, IDGoogle, UltimaVisita, FechaVisita, Clasificacion FROM dbo.Lead";

            JsonArray ja = ExecQuery(query);
            
            if (ja.Count > 0) {
                var format = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss"; // DateTime format
                var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = format };
                list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Lead>>(ja.ToString(), dateTimeConverter)!;
            }
            else
                list = NotFound("There are no leads");

            Console.WriteLine("return");
            return list;
        }
```

In console i can read the line "return" that i send before the return and then stops and stays there thinking until I stop the project in Visual Studio.

I tried send only one lead and it returns without problems. I tried to print in console the list of leads that i get from the DB and it's all correct too.

EDIT: If I call all the columns that I need, it takes 11 min to return me the result. I have ñ and ç chars, can be this the problem?

Comment: This sounds like a deadlock, but who knows. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I tried to. I'm new here and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @JudiithGV How much data has list?

Comment: It has 45 columns and 1828 rows.

Comment: That's not a lot of data for serializing it.  How much have you waited for the data to return before killing the process?

Comment: Like a 10 minutes. It process the data and goes to the return line in less than a minute and then stays there thinking.

Comment: 10 minutes is a long time. Try to enable debugging level logs for ASP.NET Core - there might be something going on when serializing the data. You could also try to use System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeObject(list) and see how long that takes

Comment: Any progress? And if you tried to select only one row? like select * from table where id=xx

Comment: If I select only one row, it returns fast and without problems. I tried to select 4 and 5 columns of all rows and no problems too.

Comment: Then I think it's better to try to get some error log for troubleshooting, did you get any error information in your logs? Or did you find that when you query some specific lines will cause the issue? Since you said it's ok for you to select only one row.. By the way, can you add some filter in your query instead of using select all in your application?

Comment: I don't get any error information, the specific line where is the issue is in the last line (`return list;`). If I add some filter is still the same result. I edited with the filters I have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was because in return line the function was making the view for the swagger result (10 minutes is a lot of time for this view!).

I done a petition with reactJS and it was really faster.

Thank you all for help me!